# Ordering of proper nouns in a list

Tags: lists

While co-editing a document, I was bothered by the list:

> ... Iran, Iraq, Libya, Yemen, Somalia, Sudan, and Syria ...

I remember being taught to order lists alphabetically if no other logical ordering exists. I proposed:

> ... Iran, Iraq, Libya, Somalia, Sudan, Syria and Yemen ...

Is my proposition "better" or am I just being a pedant?

Comment: In case of Places, the names may be written as they occur from East to west ( or reverse). Or clockwise/anti clockwise as they occur with respect to a point of reference. That doesn't seem to be the case here though.

Comment: You forgot a comma.

Comment: It was intentional. Do I really need an Oxford comma in this list?

Comment: Interestingly, a Google search for ["Iran, Iraq, Libya, Yemen, Somalia, Sudan, and Syria"](https://www.google.com/search?q="Iran%2C+Iraq%2C+Libya%2C+Yemen%2C+Somalia%2C+Sudan%2C+and+Syria") turns up 2 newspapers now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you were instructed correctly.
I see nothing in History, Geography, or Topography that places *Yemen* anywhere but out of place on this list.
I think I would certainly note for correction the order of this list. If there were an unstated reason for the current order, it should be the object of an edit by the author. If the author is not involved, then ordering the list alphabetically seems correct.
Alphabetizing lists serves a useful function by allowing a reader to find something on a list easier.